# Assetic Symfony2 less+compress filter

Tags: symfony, filter, compression, less, assetic

Is there a way to make assetic automatically compile **and** compress .less files?

I tried this config:

```
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: true
bundles:        ['BloggerBlogBundle', "FOSCommentBundle"]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    less:
      node: /home/igor/nvm/v0.8.16/bin/node
      node_paths: [/home/igor/nvm/bin/node_modules]
      apply_to: "\.less$"
    yui_css:
      jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
      apply_to: "\.css$|\.less"
```

But this results in **.css** files getting compressed and  **.less** files getting compiled. **I can't make it do both: compile and then compress my .less files.**

Answer (score 9):

Here is my config and twig code for compiling + compressing .less files in the same time:

config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    java: %java_path%
    filters:
        less:
            node:       %node_base_path%
            node_paths: [%node_lib_path%, %node_modules_path%]
        cssrewrite: ~
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%%jar_file%
        yui_js:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%%jar_file%
```

In my twig:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/event.less'
        'css/colorpicker.css'
        filter='less,?yui_css'
        output='build/event_layout_2cols.css'
    %}
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

And here is the command to both compile AND compress:

```
./app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Hope that help!

Comment: I was struggling with this until I realised you need to clear the cache for prod **before** running `assetic:dump`. After that, the above method worked for me.